# Generating a json schemas that validate both root lists and mappings using pydantic

Tags: python, jsonschema, pydantic

I am trying to write a schema that can be used to validate two different requirements formats, a v1 which used to be a list at root level and a newer one that is using a mapping:

```
# requirements.yml v1
- {}  # the mapping inside being a RoleModel
...
```

```
# requirements.yml v2
roles:
  - {}  # the mapping inside being a RoleModel
  ...
collections:
  - {}  # the mapping inside being a CollectionModel
  ...
```

I was able to generate different schemas for either of these versions but I have no idea how can I combine the two versions into a single schema.

For practical reasons I cannot use different schemas as the filenames are the same and Ansible loads both, so there is no way to determine the schema before opening the file.

For v2 fommat I do have an implementation at https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint/blob/schemas/src/ansiblelint/schemas/requirements.py

I did learn that in order to validate lists at root level, I need to do something like https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint/blob/schemas/src/ansiblelint/schemas/playbook.py#L35 :

```
top_level_schema = schema([RoleModel], title='Requiremetns v1 Schema')
```

How can I combine the two in a single schema, one that would cover both examples listed above?

Comment: I could tell you how to do this in JSON Schema, but I know nothing of pydantic. It looks like JSON Schemas are generated from Python types?

Comment: Can you share the resulting schema for both scripts please?

Comment: Sure, generated schemas are at https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint/tree/schemas/src/ansiblelint/data and the source code at https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint/tree/schemas/src/ansiblelint/schemas --- the triky one is the requirements one, as the only one that has two forms, as a sequence (v1) or as a mapping in (v2).

Answer (score 0):

For JSON Schema, you want to use an applicator which has an array of schema values.

Based on the code you've shown me, the playbook schema doesn't actually generate a useful schema (only has definitions, no actual validation).

Based on the docs for pydantic, it looks like you want to use a Union type.

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#json-schema-types

> Union[str, int]
> anyOf
> {"anyOf": [{"type": "string"}, {"type": "integer"}]}

This same approach MIGHT work with your defined classes, but I have no way to test.

If not, I suggest you file an issue on their github repo.
Although, I've found a similar feature request already: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/2036